# Обновление статики в Django c Docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, deploy

в `Dockerfile` для `Django` есть команда сбора статики в процессе сборки:

```
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
```

В `docker-compose` директория, в которую собирается статика привязана к volume

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./src
    command: gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
    expose:
      - 8000

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

При первом запуске этого docker-compose все нормально, статика собирается, volume создается. Но если затем в исходниках добавить что-то в статику и пересобрать заново - новые файлы в volume не добавляются. Если удалить volume и пересобрать, то статика снова соберется нормально.

Почему не добавляются новые файлы в volume?

Comment: Какой командой пересобираете?

Comment: Потому что volume инициализируется только один раз при создании: если его не существует, то копируется содержимое из образа в volumne один раз, а больше он никак и никогда не трогается https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container

Comment: @andreymal то есть никакого способа именно обновить статику нет? Только удалить volume и создать заново?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте обновлять каждый раз статику в компоузе

```
command: > 
      bash -c "pip install -r requirements.txt && ./manage.py migrate && ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput && \\
        gunicorn src.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
```